Find the list of different values in 2 tables by id key
I have 2 tables with the same IDs but different values for some cells. I want to find the different values on the new tab in the following format:
Id, sheet1_field, sheet2_field, sheet1_data, sheet2_data.
What is the best way to do this?
Please find the example and the expected result in the following spreadsheet - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1W9aLJZoypoFT7xyKdpk1rXhTL1BVruZpbpoPhzKswmU/edit?gid=1041107819#gid=1041107819

In your results tab, what are sheet1_field, sheet2_field?! Are they inputs as well along with the given ID?

sheet1_field is the column name from sheet1, sheet2_field - the column name from sheet2. They can be not the same. E.g. delivery_cost in sheet1 and delivery_cost_t in sheet2.

I need to compare the values ​​of different fields by ID and get a list of IDs and values ​​where the data is different in both sheets.


You may try:
=let(Λ,tocol(,1), reduce(Λ,Sheet1!B2:index(Sheet1!E:E,match(,0/(Sheet1!A:A<>""))),lambda(a,x,vstack(if(iserr(+a),Λ,a),let(r,row(x),c,column(x),z,index(Sheet1!A:A,r),
    Σ,vlookup(z,choosecols(Sheet2!A:E,1,c),2,),if(x=Σ,Λ,hstack(z,index(Sheet1!1:1,c),index(Sheet2!1:1,c),x,Σ)))))))



Thank you! For this formula to work, the columns in the two tables need to be in the same order, right? Is it possible to make it work when they are mixed, or when one of them contains an extra field?
